# How to deal with poll() without slowing server or wasting cpu?

Tags: c, server, cpu, polling, usleep

I ran into an interesting problem with my homemade server in C.

The mainline part is summed up as follows:

```
while(donotend==1){
    if (somethingdetected==1){
    //do critical code
    }
    if (poll(structs,numberoffields,x) < 1){continue;}
    //do functions based on poll fields that were filled in
}
```

What I noticed greatly is that `poll()` determines the speed of output as well as CPU usage.

If I set the last parameter x (the timeout value) to zero, then CPU usage for the program alone is above 95%, but each request to the server is processed instantly.

If however, I set x to 500, then cpu usage is still above 95% but it takes 2 seconds for a request to be processed.

If I use `usleep(500)` just before `poll()` then cpu usage goes down to almost nothing and it takes no time for a request to processed.

This is what I don't understand:

Why wouldn't poll have up to the number of milliseconds specified in the last parameter to catch an event and return when at least one is found instead of always waiting the full millisecond timeout?

and What would be the effective usleep value? I feel specifying too high of a usleep value will cause the normal program execution to lock up while specifying too low of one won't have an effect.

Comment: Just a guess: you are poll()ing on filedescriptors that are always writeble / readable, (such as write to stdout / stderr) This could be caused by setting unused fds to zero(stdin_fileno)    (memset?) , instead of -1. or by failing to remove fds from the set.

Comment: You're using `poll` incorrectly, but we'd have to see more code to know exactly what you're doing wrong. Likely you're polling some sockets for writability even if you don't want to write to them.

Comment: I'm polling for any readability/writability on the socket and the function that happens after is based on whether the socket is readable or writeable.

Comment: the check of the returned value needs to include the value 0, otherwise the code will be trying to handle events that never happened.  Suggest reading the man page paragraph titled 'RETURNS'

Comment: The functionality between the poll call and the end of the endless loop requires at least one of the events to be set on any descriptor. that's why I used `continue;` if the poll value is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

reading the man page for `poll()` gives a completely different story about the parameters and the meaning of the parameters

Here is a relevant excerpt from the man page:

Description

poll() performs a similar task to select(2): it waits for one of a set of file descriptors to become ready to perform I/O.

The set of file descriptors to be monitored is specified in the fds argument, which is an array of structures of the following form: 
struct pollfd {
    int   fd;         /* file descriptor */
    short events;     /* requested events */
    short revents;    /* returned events */
};
The caller should specify the number of items in the fds array in nfds. 
The field fd contains a file descriptor for an open file. If this field is negative, then the corresponding events field is ignored and the revents field returns zero. (This provides an easy way of ignoring a file descriptor for a single poll() call: simply negate the fd field.)

The field events is an input parameter, a bit mask specifying the events the application is interested in for the file descriptor fd. If this field is specified as zero, then all events are ignored for fd and revents returns zero.

The field revents is an output parameter, filled by the kernel with the events that actually occurred. The bits returned in revents can include any of those specified in events, or one of the values POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL. (These three bits are meaningless in the events field, and will be set in the revents field whenever the corresponding condition is true.)

If none of the events requested (and no error) has occurred for any of the file descriptors, then poll() blocks until one of the events occurs.

The timeout argument specifies the minimum number of milliseconds that poll() will block. (This interval will be rounded up to the system clock granularity, and kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking interval may overrun by a small amount.) Specifying a negative value in timeout means an infinite timeout. Specifying a timeout of zero causes poll() to return immediately, even if no file descriptors are ready.

--end excerpt

Somehow, I do not see a relation between how `poll()` should be called and what it does, compared to the posted code.

Perhaps you could address this relationship in your question.